# Rank order grouped data in MySQL without session variables?

Tags: mysql, sql, session-variables, ranking, rank

My data looks like this:

```
Table Name = sales_orders

Customer_id| Order_id| Item_Id
-------------------------------
1          | 1      | 10
1          | 1      | 24
1          | 1      | 37
1          | 2      | 11
1          | 2      | 15
1          | 3      | 28
2          | 4      | 37
4          | 6      | 10
2          | 7      | 10
```

However, I need it to look like this:

```
Customer_id| Order_id| Item_Id |Order_rank
------------------------------------------
1          | 1      | 10       |    1   
1          | 1      | 24       |    1
1          | 1      | 37       |    1
1          | 2      | 11       |    2
1          | 2      | 15       |    2
1          | 3      | 28       |    3
2          | 4      | 37       |    1
4          | 6      | 10       |    1
2          | 7      | 10       |    2
```

Customer_Id is a unique person

Order_id is a unique order

item_id is the product code

To further explain, the first three lines are from Customer #1's first order (order_id = 1) where this person ordered 3 different items (10,24, and 37). They then purchased another order (order_id =2) with two other products. Person with customer_id =2 has 2 unique orders (4 and 6), while customer with ID '4' has one unique order (order_id =6)

Essentially, what I need to do is rank these orders by customer_id and order Id, so that I can say "Order_id = 7 is the second order for customer_id = 2, because Order_rank = 2"

The challenge here is that I can't use session variables (e.g. @grp := customer_id ) in the MySQL query

For example, a query such as this is NOT allowed:

```
SELECT 
customer_id,
order_id,
@ss := CASE WHEN @grp = customer_id THEN @ss + 1 ELSE 1 END AS 
order_rank,
@grp := customer_id 
FROM 
(
SELECT 
customer_id,
order_id
FROM sales_orders
GROUP BY customer_id, order_id
ORDER BY customer_id, order_id ASC
) AS t_1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ss := 0, @grp = NULL)ss

ORDER BY customer_id asc
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html), we can `Count(..)` the **unique and previous** `order_id` values for a specific row's `customer_id` and `order_id` to determine the rank.

We need to count **unique** values because you have multiple rows per order (due to multiple items).

---

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  t1.Customer_id, 
  t1.Order_id, 
  t1.Item_Id, 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Order_id) 
   FROM sales_orders t2 
   WHERE t2.Customer_id = t1.Customer_id AND 
         t2.Order_id <= t1.Order_id
  ) AS Order_rank 
FROM sales_orders AS t1;
```

**Result**

```
| Customer_id | Order_id | Item_Id | Order_rank |
| ----------- | -------- | ------- | ---------- |
| 1           | 1        | 10      | 1          |
| 1           | 1        | 24      | 1          |
| 1           | 1        | 37      | 1          |
| 1           | 2        | 11      | 2          |
| 1           | 2        | 15      | 2          |
| 1           | 3        | 28      | 3          |
| 2           | 4        | 37      | 1          |
| 4           | 6        | 10      | 1          |
| 2           | 7        | 10      | 2          |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/arZThBVrh6Xsb1u26byUJ6/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select so.*,
       (select count(*)
        from sales_orders so2
        where so2.Customer_id = so.Customer_id and
              so2.order_id <= so.order_id
       ) as rank_order
from sales_orders so;
```

Or in MySQL 8+:

```
select so.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by Customer_Id order by Order_Id) as rank_order
from sales_orders so;
```